# What does "filters per unit" means?

Tags: neural-networks

I met the following phrase [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6082v4.pdf):

> first hidden layer contains maxout units with three filters per unit

What does it mean exactly? Maxout unit is neuron, which outputs maximum of inputs, right? And what are "filters"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the *Maxout Networks* paper, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.4389v4.pdf,

> In a convolutional network, a maxout feature map can be constructed
>   by taking the maximum across k affine feature maps (i.e., pool across channels, in addition spatial locations).

the number of parameters of a maxout layer is $d\times m\times k$, where $d$ is the dimension of the input, $m$ is the number of maxout units, and $k$ is the number of affine feature maps (filters) per unit.

So essentially, compared to ReLU, a maxout unit replaces the non-linearity $max(0,x)$ with $\max\limits_k W_jx+b_j$ via taking the maximum of $k$ sets of different $W$ (filters).